# How To Customize UI Library React-WeUI To Minimize Size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, customization, wechat

Looking at this UI Library, https://github.com/weui/react-weui I want specific components from it like Dialog and Button but npm installing the entire package and using it doubles my file sizes.

I'm really rusty with web dev so I'm struggling to identify the best way to cherry pick the components I want. I looked through the github and I can maybe drag and drop the js, css files into my project but is that the best way?

Comment: Sometimes libraries will let you piece it out, but it's not a standard and not everyone does that. If size is really a big issue, then yeah you can just add the .js and .css files to your project manually. Not the ideal solution, but it will work in a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is just to look at the source and add the .js and .css files manually